# How to upload a single image to a folder?

Tags: jquery, image, upload

i need to upload a single image to a folder. im also have some text boxes in my form. if i user `enctype="multipart/form-data"` means the getParameter does not recognized. i don't like to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. how to upload? any Jquery plugin? or some other else?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_FILES`

Easy tutorial can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Using jQuery is not necesarry

Answer (score 0):

jQuery upload: [here](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).
You can go to downloads and get all the source code in a zip archive.